# Setting margin requirements for futures contracts in Quantstrat/Blotter/FinancialInstrument

Tags: algorithmic-trading

I can't find the way to set up the margin requirements for futures contracts when testing trading strategies with Quantstrat. I don't realize how to do it when defining the instruments to run the test on, nor via

```
stock()
```

neither

```
future()
```

functions of FinancialInstruments. Without the margin settled, the test considers the selected futures on a cash basis (as if they were stocks or ETFs) and that makes the results quite unreal beacause leaves aside the effect of leverage that trading on margin gives when dealing with futures.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe leverage in futures is accounted for by `multiplier` and `initeq`.

```
future("CL", multiplier = "1000", currency = "USD")
tradesize <- 1
initeq <- 40000
```

Doing so would be trading 1 lot on a 40k initial equity account (quantity set as 1 in trading rules as well).

Returns for futures can be calculated in many ways. IMHO calculating returns on required margin is of no value. Its the money put aside for the trade or strategy that matters. What does it matter if the margin for CL is 5k if for every lot one needs 40k? How much one needs should be determined based on the risk of a strategy.